# mode-line-inactive after system window loses focus

Tags: mode-line, linux, x11, focus

When a system/X11 window (frame) with Emacs loses focus, how can I make its mode line become `mode-line-inactive`? It stays active, keeping the standard `mode-line` look/face…

Shouldn’t it be the default? Seems pretty natural.